# Finding the sketch of the original function from a sketch of its derivative

Tags: integration

[image]

Let's just say I had a graph like the one above but I didn't know its equation. Let's also say it's the graph of a derivative function and I had to find the graph of the original function between x = -2 and x = 4. How would finding the area underneath the graph, between these two points help me to sketch the original function?

NOTE: I have a homework question very similar to this but with a different graph. I just wanted to figure out or understand the method behind how finding the area underneath the derivative function between these two points can help with the sketch of the original function.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the area under your plotted curve is the integral of that curve, up to a constant value. I found the YouTube series [Essense of Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM) by 3Blue1Brown is helpful for beginning to understand calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to make a comment but my points weren't enough. Anyway, can we approximate the answer? If yes then you can look here for some techniques of approximating integration: [Approximating Integral](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ApproximatingDefIntegrals.aspx)

Comment: You can. I just wanted to know how I can use that area to draw the original function.

Comment: When you explain it like that, I start questioning my intelligence. Cheers, man!

Comment: @user411697  I would first notice that $f(0) = f^{\prime} (0) = 0$ because area under that 
 is zero.  Then I would find $\int_{0}^{t} f^{\prime}(x) dx = f(t) $ for all $ t \geqslant -2 $ and $t \leqslant 4$.  Then I would just make a table and plot those points and approximate the original function.